# Eclipse shows error for OpenCV cvCvtColor while using javacv

Tags: android, opencv, javacv

I used [javaCV](http://code.google.com/p/javacv/) for my android application:
When I'm trying to covert an image into a grayscale image, eclipse cannot find the constant CV_BGR2GRAY.

can anyone help me out? Thank you.

```
  cvCvtColor(originalImage,grayImage,CV_BGR2GRAY);
```

Also,
eclipse cannot find the constant for CASCADE_FILE in

```
 CvHaarClassifierCascade cascade = new CvHaarClassifierCascade(cvLoad(CASCADE_FILE));
```

Comment: how do you think we can help?by imagining the error??please post some code an error messages if you want to recieve attention and answers

Comment: sorry, I'm not stating it clearly. Eclipse cannot find all these constants above. I'm new to openCV, trying to test this example:http://tkgospodinov.com/computer-vision-face-detection-in-java-with-opencv-using-javacv/

Comment: let me know if you fixed the problem!

Comment: Thank you very much. I ended up directly inputting the integer.

Comment: The `opencv_imgproc` class contains that constant: http://code.google.com/p/javacv/source/browse/trunk/javacv/src/com/googlecode/javacv/cpp/opencv_imgproc.java#153

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am using OpenCV in C/C++ version, but the concepts I'm pointing are still valid.

OpenCV constant `CV_BGR2GRAY` belongs to an enumerative type defined in the source file `types_c.h`:

> /* Constants for color conversion */
>
> enum {
>
> ```
> CV_BGR2BGRA    =0,
> CV_RGB2RGBA    =CV_BGR2BGRA,
>
> CV_BGRA2BGR    =1,
> CV_RGBA2RGB    =CV_BGRA2BGR,
>
> CV_BGR2RGBA    =2,
> CV_RGB2BGRA    =CV_BGR2RGBA,
>
> CV_RGBA2BGR    =3,
> CV_BGRA2RGB    =CV_RGBA2BGR,
>
> CV_BGR2RGB     =4,
> CV_RGB2BGR     =CV_BGR2RGB,
>
> CV_BGRA2RGBA   =5,
> CV_RGBA2BGRA   =CV_BGRA2RGBA,
>
> CV_BGR2GRAY    =6,
> CV_RGB2GRAY    =7,
> CV_GRAY2BGR    =8,
> CV_GRAY2RGB    =CV_GRAY2BGR,
> CV_GRAY2BGRA   =9,
> CV_GRAY2RGBA   =CV_GRAY2BGRA,
> CV_BGRA2GRAY   =10,
> CV_RGBA2GRAY   =11,
>
> CV_BGR2BGR565  =12,
> CV_RGB2BGR565  =13,
> CV_BGR5652BGR  =14,
> CV_BGR5652RGB  =15,
> CV_BGRA2BGR565 =16,
> CV_RGBA2BGR565 =17,
> CV_BGR5652BGRA =18,
> CV_BGR5652RGBA =19,
>
> CV_GRAY2BGR565 =20,
> CV_BGR5652GRAY =21,
>
> CV_BGR2BGR555  =22,
> CV_RGB2BGR555  =23,
> CV_BGR5552BGR  =24,
> CV_BGR5552RGB  =25,
> CV_BGRA2BGR555 =26,
> CV_RGBA2BGR555 =27,
> CV_BGR5552BGRA =28,
> CV_BGR5552RGBA =29,
>
> CV_GRAY2BGR555 =30,
> CV_BGR5552GRAY =31,
>
> CV_BGR2XYZ     =32,
> CV_RGB2XYZ     =33,
> CV_XYZ2BGR     =34,
> CV_XYZ2RGB     =35,
>
> CV_BGR2YCrCb   =36,
> CV_RGB2YCrCb   =37,
> CV_YCrCb2BGR   =38,
> CV_YCrCb2RGB   =39,
>
> CV_BGR2HSV     =40,
> CV_RGB2HSV     =41,
>
> CV_BGR2Lab     =44,
> CV_RGB2Lab     =45,
>
> CV_BayerBG2BGR =46,
> CV_BayerGB2BGR =47,
> CV_BayerRG2BGR =48,
> CV_BayerGR2BGR =49,
>
> CV_BayerBG2RGB =CV_BayerRG2BGR,
> CV_BayerGB2RGB =CV_BayerGR2BGR,
> CV_BayerRG2RGB =CV_BayerBG2BGR,
> CV_BayerGR2RGB =CV_BayerGB2BGR,
>
> CV_BGR2Luv     =50,
> CV_RGB2Luv     =51,
> CV_BGR2HLS     =52,
> CV_RGB2HLS     =53,
>
> CV_HSV2BGR     =54,
> CV_HSV2RGB     =55,
>
> CV_Lab2BGR     =56,
> CV_Lab2RGB     =57,
> CV_Luv2BGR     =58,
> CV_Luv2RGB     =59,
> CV_HLS2BGR     =60,
> CV_HLS2RGB     =61,
>
> CV_BayerBG2BGR_VNG =62,
> CV_BayerGB2BGR_VNG =63,
> CV_BayerRG2BGR_VNG =64,
> CV_BayerGR2BGR_VNG =65,
>
> CV_BayerBG2RGB_VNG =CV_BayerRG2BGR_VNG,
> CV_BayerGB2RGB_VNG =CV_BayerGR2BGR_VNG,
> CV_BayerRG2RGB_VNG =CV_BayerBG2BGR_VNG,
> CV_BayerGR2RGB_VNG =CV_BayerGB2BGR_VNG,
>
> CV_BGR2HSV_FULL = 66,
> CV_RGB2HSV_FULL = 67,
> CV_BGR2HLS_FULL = 68,
> CV_RGB2HLS_FULL = 69,
>
> CV_HSV2BGR_FULL = 70,
> CV_HSV2RGB_FULL = 71,
> CV_HLS2BGR_FULL = 72,
> CV_HLS2RGB_FULL = 73,
>
> CV_LBGR2Lab     = 74,
> CV_LRGB2Lab     = 75,
> CV_LBGR2Luv     = 76,
> CV_LRGB2Luv     = 77,
>
> CV_Lab2LBGR     = 78,
> CV_Lab2LRGB     = 79,
> CV_Luv2LBGR     = 80,
> CV_Luv2LRGB     = 81,
>
> CV_BGR2YUV      = 82,
> CV_RGB2YUV      = 83,
> CV_YUV2BGR      = 84,
> CV_YUV2RGB      = 85,
>
> CV_BayerBG2GRAY = 86,
> CV_BayerGB2GRAY = 87,
> CV_BayerRG2GRAY = 88,
> CV_BayerGR2GRAY = 89,
>
> CV_YUV420i2RGB  = 90,
> CV_YUV420i2BGR  = 91,
> CV_YUV420sp2RGB = 92,
> CV_YUV420sp2BGR = 93,
>
> CV_COLORCVT_MAX  =100 };
> ```

First of all check if `types_c.h` header file is correctly included in library's source files: on my UNIX system I've found it at path `/usr/local/include/opencv2/imgproc/types_c.h`.

If it is there it might simply be a problem in your compilation options: be sure you are correctly **including** and **linking** all library files.

In my case I specified library's search path with the following:

- `-L/usr/local/lib`
- `-lopencv_core` `-lopencv_highgui`

and obviously included libraries for the compiler:

- `-I/usr/local/include/opencv`

If it still isn't working just try to call function `cv::cvCvtColor()` specifying value 6 as last input parameter (it's the ***int*** corresponding to the enumerative type constant `CV_BGR2GRAY`):

```
cvCvtColor(originalImage,grayImage, 6 );
```

Regarding your second error I don't know what to say, it may be due to the same problems I've stated before.

Check if resolving the first one also fixes the second.

AND PLEASE PUT MORE EFFORT IN YOUR QUESTIONS!

Answer (score 1):

I think this constant is: org.opencv.imgproc.ImgProc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY

Why it's not CV_BGR2GRAY is an artefact of the automatic conversion of the C interface to Java.

*(And the question is perfectly clear and relevant, if you know about OpenCV Java. If you don't, why post 100 lines about the C/C++ interface and moan at the questioner).*

Answer (score 0):

here “import org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc”

Answer (score 0):

Please import this static parameter in your top of ActivityClass File.

**import static org.bytedeco.javacpp.opencv_imgproc.CV_BGR2GRAY;**

you can use CV_BGR2GRAY after this.